# How can I filter results based on multiple selections from dropdown?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material2

I'm following the material table example from Angular Material and currently, they have a filtering the table example with typed in results.

I added two dropdowns to the material table example and I want to be able to select a value from both dropdowns and perform a search based on both values from the two dropdowns. E.g. in this case, if I select 8 and Hydrogen, I should not get any results because 8 and hydrogen are not part of the same record/item. If I select however 1 and hydrogen, I should get back hydrogen because 1 and hydrogen values are part of the same item/record.

Here's the stackbiltz:  https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-t67ae3-huzvd6?file=app%2Ftable-filtering-example.ts

Here's the code snippets:

component:

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {MatTableDataSource} from '@angular/material';

/**
 * @title Table with filtering
 */
@Component({
  selector: 'table-filtering-example',
  styleUrls: ['table-filtering-example.css'],
  templateUrl: 'table-filtering-example.html',
})
export class TableFilteringExample {
  displayedColumns = ['position', 'name', 'weight', 'symbol'];
  dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(ELEMENT_DATA);

//How do I filter based on selected value? 
  search(selectedValue: string, selectedValueEle: string) {
      selectedValue = selectedValue.trim(); // Remove whitespace
    selectedValue = selectedValue.toLowerCase(); // MatTableDataSource defaults to lowercase matches
     this.dataSource.filter = selectedValue && selectedValueEle;
     debugger 
  }
}

export interface Element {
  name: string;
  position: number;
  weight: number;
  symbol: string;
}

const ELEMENT_DATA: Element[] = [
  {position: 1, name: 'Hydrogen', weight: 1.0079, symbol: 'H'},
  {position: 2, name: 'Helium', weight: 4.0026, symbol: 'He'},
  {position: 3, name: 'Lithium', weight: 6.941, symbol: 'Li'},
  {position: 4, name: 'Beryllium', weight: 9.0122, symbol: 'Be'},
  {position: 5, name: 'Boron', weight: 10.811, symbol: 'B'},
  {position: 6, name: 'Carbon', weight: 12.0107, symbol: 'C'},
  {position: 7, name: 'Nitrogen', weight: 14.0067, symbol: 'N'},
  {position: 8, name: 'Oxygen', weight: 15.9994, symbol: 'O'},
  {position: 9, name: 'Fluorine', weight: 18.9984, symbol: 'F'},
  {position: 10, name: 'Neon', weight: 20.1797, symbol: 'Ne'},
  {position: 11, name: 'Sodium', weight: 22.9897, symbol: 'Na'},
  {position: 12, name: 'Magnesium', weight: 24.305, symbol: 'Mg'},
  {position: 13, name: 'Aluminum', weight: 26.9815, symbol: 'Al'},
  {position: 14, name: 'Silicon', weight: 28.0855, symbol: 'Si'},
  {position: 15, name: 'Phosphorus', weight: 30.9738, symbol: 'P'},
  {position: 16, name: 'Sulfur', weight: 32.065, symbol: 'S'},
  {position: 17, name: 'Chlorine', weight: 35.453, symbol: 'Cl'},
  {position: 18, name: 'Argon', weight: 39.948, symbol: 'Ar'},
  {position: 19, name: 'Potassium', weight: 39.0983, symbol: 'K'},
  {position: 20, name: 'Calcium', weight: 40.078, symbol: 'Ca'},
];
```

html:

```
<div class="example-container mat-elevation-z8">
  <div class="example-header">

    <select #selectedValueEle>
      <option value="8">8</option>
      <option value="9">9</option>
    </select>
    <select #selectedValue>
      <option value="Hydrogen">Hydrogen</option>
      <option value="Helium">Helium</option>
    </select>
    <button (click)="search(selectedValue.value, selectedValueEle.value)">Search</button>
    <mat-form-field>
      <input matInput (keyup)="applyFilter($event.target.value)" placeholder="Filter">
    </mat-form-field>
  </div>

  <mat-table #table [dataSource]="dataSource">

    <!-- Position Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="position">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> No. </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.position}} </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <!-- Name Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Name </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.name}} </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <!-- Weight Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="weight">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Weight </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.weight}} </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <!-- Symbol Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="symbol">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Symbol </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.symbol}} </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
    <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></mat-row>
  </mat-table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you replace the line:

```
this.dataSource.filter = selectedValue && selectedValueEle;
```

with:

```
this.dataSource.filter = selectedValueEle + selectedValue;
```

that should do the trick!

This is because according to the Angular table documentation https://material.angular.io/components/table/overview#filtering:

> For example, the data object {id: 123, name: 'Mr. Smith', favoriteColor: 'blue'} will be reduced to 123mr. smithblue. If your filter string was blue then it would be considered a match because it is contained in the reduced string, and the row would be displayed in the table.

From what I understand, they're doing a simple string search. So by concatenating the value and the element, it's doing a string search on "1Hydrogen" and finds it in the reduced data object, "1Hydrogen1.0079H."

But you must have it in the order of "1Hydrogen," so by having `selectedValueEle` be first and `selectedValue` next, you'll have it in the correct format. Hope this helped and good luck!

Comment: If I try 2 and Helium, it doesn't work though. Why is that?

Comment: Ah, I see what went wrong. It actually doesn't work if flipped! I just got lucky because Hydrogen happened to be followed by a 1 after. Keeping it in the format of "1Hydrogen" and thus "2Helium" will work! I've since updated my answer to reflect this, so please use the fixed version!

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help!