# reusable MAT-TABLE dropdown filter is not working

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm trying to achieve like this [EXAMPLE](https://fooplugins.github.io/FooTable/docs/examples/advanced/filter-dropdown.html) in reusable table. But seems it is not working.

[my stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/resuable-datatable-hgymjx?file=src%2Fapp%2Fshared%2Fdata-table%2Fdata-table.component.ts)

data-table.ts

```
export class DropdownOption {
  filterOption : [];
}

  @Input() control: FormControl;
  @Input() options: DropdownOption[];
  @Output() selectionChange = new EventEmitter<MatSelectChange>();

  onSelectionChange(event) {
    this.selectionChange.next(event);
  }
```

target.component

```
<h3>table 1</h3>
  <app-data-table [tableData]="tableData1" [columnHeader]="columnHeader1" (selectionChange)="onSelectionChange($event)"></app-data-table>

  <h3>table 2</h3>
  <app-data-table [tableData]="tableData2" [columnHeader]="columnHeader2"> </app-data-table>
</div>
```

Problem is:

1. i've add selectOption for 1st table only.. but its reflecting in my
   2nd table also.
2. is my model correct

   ```
   export class DropdownOption {
     filterOption : [];
   }
   ```

   ?

Comment: I dont see any select options passed into your table component

Comment: @VimalPatel thats where i got stuck :( .. and having some confusion in model also (interface)

Comment: For interface you only need @Input() options: filterOption : []; like this.

Comment: is it possible to create stackblitz pls?

Comment: What exactly are you looking for?

Comment: @VimalPatel am looking for reusable mat-table component with search and dropdown filter..!! .. like my mat-table should be generic and i should reuse that in any number of different components..thats what im trying to create in my stackblitz.. but endup with some understanding issue

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235321/discussion-between-vimal-patel-and-mr-learner).

Comment: see that first you need know how to add multiple filters in angular mat table, you has an example in this SO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68495473/how-to-add-multiple-filters-in-angular-mat-table/68496521#68496521

Answer (score 0):

After know how create a custom filter based in two conditions like this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68495473/how-to-add-multiple-filters-in-angular-mat-table/68496521#68496521), I can imagine an options like

```
options={column:'status',options:['Any status','Active','Disabled']}
```

you only need create a FormGroup with two fields, "the filter" and the "dropdown"

```
field:string:null;
options:any[];
form:FormGroup;
subscription:any;
@Input('options') set options(value){
   this.field=value.column
   this.options=value.options
   this.form=new FormGroup({
     filter:new FormControl();
     select:new FormControl(0);
   })
   if (this.subscription)
      this.subscription.unsubscribe();

   this.subscription=this.form.valueChanges(res=>{
        ..here call to filter..
   }) 
}
```

You use the variable "options" to create the select

Comment: Luckily  just found your answer from [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54359980/filter-based-on-multiple-drop-down-selection-in-mat-table) .... this is what am actually trying to convert as reusable component... can you pls help me on that